# Localize type arguments in XAML (e.g. x:String)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, localization, internationalization, xamarin.forms

In [Localizing Xamarin.Forms Apps with RESX Resource Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) one can translate strings, images and so on. You can do this most of the time:

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate NotesLabel}" />
```

Now I want to use a `Picker`:

```
<Picker x:Name="IndustryTypePicker1" SelectedIndex="{Binding Industry}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>1</x:String> 
        <x:String>2</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Here we use `<x:String>` tags. How can these type arguments be localized in XAML? Or is this only possible in code?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried, but this could work:

```xml
<Picker>
  <Picker.Items>
    <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="1" />
    <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="2" />
  </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

To get it to work with `XamlC` on, you might have to fix the signature of the `TranslateExtension` from:

```cs
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
```

to:

```cs
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<string>
```

and implement the new interface:

```cs
string IMarkupExtension<string>.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ...
    return translation;    
}

object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return (this as IMarkupExtension<string>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```

Comment: Now I tried your approach. Here I get `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` when the first translated item of the picker is returned at `string IMarkupExtension<string>.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` and then at `object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)`.

Comment: the exception without context is not helpful. It might look like a bug. Please file that to bugzilla and we'll have a look at it

Comment: Now I created a fresh project and here I get `System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'ProjectName.TranslateExtension' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.` I also tried it with the [UsingResxLocalization](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UsingResxLocalization) example and I get the same error message.

Comment: Hi Stephane. The translation seems to work fine in the latest version of XF. The only thing missing is the conversion to `String` in the XAML. How can I do this?